# why my python program cannot find modules?

Tags: python, linux, bash, virtual-environment

I set the directory of my own modules into PATH in .bashrc. I also set the path into the environment of python. However, my program cannot find those modules in module directory unless I add following scripts:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/.../module/directory")
```

Considering the program may be used in the other machines or accounts, I hope to set the module directory in system directory and then it can be found by any programs.

What should I do in Linux settings or Python settings? Any further suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Comment: `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` are different and the latter gets sourced when you open a terminal window. Is your `bashrc` being sourced?

Comment: Install it as a package using setuptools.

Comment: @Matteo Ferla, thanks for your question. Yes. I did it. I can see the module directory in $PATH. However, when I run a program to call the module, it always shows the module not found.

Comment: @jordanm, thanks for your suggestion. Let me figure it out how to do it.